# Can't open Maya's help page in browser when I press F1

Tags: installation, maya, helper, autodesk

I put my Maya on C-plate, then I open it, I want to watch Maya's help so I press F1, but this page can't turn into my Chrome, I got a error, please look at these pictures:

[picture 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWvmS.png)

[picture 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB1pk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was solved this problem yesterday , Now I briefly describe my solution .

1.the error is "Window can't find UCHTML\shell\open\command", UC is browser, like Chrome , I think I have no this browser ,  so I got this error , I tried to download UC browser , then I can open help page by UC browser , Now I know registry is wrong make MAYA think open HTML page need UC browser . so I check registry.
       
 2.open Registry Editor , By modifying Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.htm and Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.html 's Default value as  ChromeHTML , Their value was originally UCHTML , change ChromeHTML Now ,then You can open help page by your chrome .